# Why does switch of branch update submodule (without explicit pull)?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I just cloned a repository, I never worked on before. It contains submodules, so I did

```
~/projects/myProject (master) $ git submodule init
~/projects/myProject (master) $ git submodule update
```

Since I needed a newer version of the submodule, I tried to update via:

```
~/projects/myProject (master) $ cd subs/mySubmodule
~/projects/myProject/subs/mySubmodule ((no branch)) $ git checkout master
~/projects/myProject/subs/mySubmodule (master) $ git pull
```

And got

```
Already up-to-date.
```

**WTF**?

After investigating the situation with removing everything and retry the whole thing, I realized that the submodule was actually updated with the branch switch and by that the pull was not necessary and the response (`Already up-to-date.`) was correct.

So why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite right to say that the switch updated the submodule. The submodule was updated when you ran `git submodule update`. Submodules are a bit weird. As [this page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) says:

> ...`git submodule update` to fetch all the data from that project and check
>   out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So, if you run `git submodule udpate`, you already have all the changes from the repo, even if the version you're seeing isn't the latest. This is because each branch has a specific commit associated with it. The code you see might be old, but the submodule will already have all the latest data. Then, when you `git checkout master` you're switching to the latest version available, and `git pull` doesn't do anything.